# Format JSON Result

Tags: json, asp.net-core, jquery-select2

Json data returned from my ASP.NET core server with:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(categories.Select(t => new { id = t.Id.ToString(), text = t.Name.ToLower() }))
```

Looks:

```
[
{
    "id": "7929d7ad-c7c3-45c5-b749-7633a478d55c",
    "text": "apparel"
},
{
    "id": "e551cbc2-9069-4c99-a66b-5824ec2610b2",
    "text": "electronics"
}]
```

But I want result like:

```
{"results":[
{
    "id": "7929d7ad-c7c3-45c5-b749-7633a478d55c",
    "text": "apparel"
},
{
    "id": "e551cbc2-9069-4c99-a66b-5824ec2610b2",
    "text": "electronics"
}]}
```

for select2. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject( new { 
results = categories.Select(t => new { id = t.Id.ToString(), text = t.Name.ToLower() }) 
} );
```